# QT Application on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I have just started application development using QtCreator on Ubuntu 14.04, so far I create a window that occupies the entire desktop, nothing else yet.  But I have a small 3 line icon in the top left of the window, I can drag it around, but there is no tool tip or context menu associated with this, what is it and how can I stop it from coming up?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new project Qt application, automatically Qt creator creates a form with a QMenuBar, a QToolBar and a QStatusBar in your QMainWindow.

To remove your small 3 lines icon, we have to open mainwindow.ui Qt form file with QtDesigner and remove QToolBar widget.